# Graphviz as Library error: too many arguments to function ‘agnode’

Tags: c, compiler-errors, graphviz

I'm trying to run a example from the "Using Graphviz as a library" in http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php.

```
#include <gvc.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Agraph_t *g;
    Agnode_t *n, *m;
    Agedge_t *e;
    Agsym_t *a;
    GVC_t *gvc;
    /* set up a graphviz context */
    gvc = gvContext();
    /* parse command line args - minimally argv[0] sets layout engine */
    gvParseArgs(gvc, argc, argv);
    /* Create a simple digraph */
    g = agopen("g", Agdirected);
    n = agnode(g, "n", 1);
    m = agnode(g, "m", 1);
    e = agedge(g, n, m, 0, 1);
    /* Set an attribute - in this case one that affects the visible rendering */
    agsafeset(n, "color", "red", "");
    /* Compute a layout using layout engine from command line args */
    gvLayoutJobs(gvc, g);
    /* Write the graph according to -T and -o options */
    gvRenderJobs(gvc, g);
    /* Free layout data */
    gvFreeLayout(gvc, g);
    /* Free graph structures */
    agclose(g);
    /* close output file, free context, and return number of errors */
    return (gvFreeContext(gvc));
}
```

I'm compiling and linking with : gcc -Wall `pkg-config libgvc --cflags --libs` *.c -o EXE -lgvc

and then I see this result:

```
graph.c: In function ‘main’:
graph.c:14:18: error: ‘Agdirected’ undeclared (first use in this function)
graph.c:14:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
graph.c:15:2: error: too many arguments to function ‘agnode’
In file included from /usr/include/graphviz/types.h:717:0,
                 from /usr/include/graphviz/gvc.h:20,
                 from graph.c:1:
/usr/include/graphviz/graph.h:185:22: note: declared here
graph.c:16:2: error: too many arguments to function ‘agnode’
In file included from /usr/include/graphviz/types.h:717:0,
                 from /usr/include/graphviz/gvc.h:20,
                 from graph.c:1:
/usr/include/graphviz/graph.h:185:22: note: declared here
graph.c:17:2: error: too many arguments to function ‘agedge’
In file included from /usr/include/graphviz/types.h:717:0,
                 from /usr/include/graphviz/gvc.h:20,
                 from graph.c:1:
/usr/include/graphviz/graph.h:192:22: note: declared here
graph.c:7:11: warning: unused variable ‘a’ [-Wunused-variable]
graph.c:6:12: warning: variable ‘e’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

Could anyone help me understand what is going on? Why the compiler is complaining about those arguments in those functions?

Thank you!!!!

Comment: What is `Agdirected`? Is it supposed to be a string? Otherwise you need to declare it. Also, all of the error messages are pretty clear, most of them are because you have to many arguments to some functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved your code as g.c, then issued this command line

```
gcc -Wall `pkg-config libgvc --cflags --libs` g.c -o EXE -lgvc
```

that yields

```
g.c: In function ‘main’:
g.c:14:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘agopen’
/usr/local/include/graphviz/cgraph.h:266:18: note: declared here
g.c:7:14: warning: unused variable ‘a’ [-Wunused-variable]
g.c:6:15: warning: variable ‘e’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

then I added the miss parameter

```
g = agopen("g", Agdirected, 0);
```

and the miss library

```
gcc -Wall `pkg-config libgvc --cflags --libs` g.c -lgvc -lcgraph
```

now the code compile and link with just 2 warnings:

```
g.c: In function ‘main’:
g.c:7:14: warning: unused variable ‘a’ [-Wunused-variable]
g.c:6:15: warning: variable ‘e’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

I think it works because I've built graphviz from source, then pkg-config is up-to-date...
The program still need some debug, running it i get:

```
./a.out

There is no layout engine support for "a.out"
Use one of: circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
Error: Layout was not done.  Missing layout plugins?
```

The message is because by default the layout engine use the exe name (i.e. a.out, default of gcc compile-and-link) as layout string...

Comment: I did what you said, however I still get the same error!

I'm using a debian 7 based system, I installed the libgraphviz from the default repo.

Comment: I think it's because pkg-config info could be old. try to add -DWITH_CGRAPH when compiling.

Comment: -DWITH_CGRAPH solved my problem, thank you very much!